# preference settings in broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver running independently from my application.
When a specific number calls, i need to trigger a service to run.
I am saving the triggering number in shared preferences within my application.
How do I get this value within my broadcast receiver so that I can check that the number calling matches before I start my service call.

I have tried the following code within my receiver to retrieve it:

variables

```
   private SharedPreferences preferenceSettingsUnique;
   private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditorUnique;
   private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
   private static final String MY_UNIQUE_SETTINGS = "MY_UNIQUE_SETTINGS";
```

In the function I have

```
 preferenceSettingsUnique = getSharedPreferences(MY_UNIQUE_SETTINGS,PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
 tracker_trigger = preferenceSettingsUnique.getString("tracker_trigger",null);
```

The value returns as null.

If anyone knows a good way to do this please.

edit showing saving procedure

```
        preferenceSettingsUnique = getSharedPreferences(MY_UNIQUE_SETTINGS,PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
    preferenceEditorUnique = preferenceSettingsUnique.edit();

    final EditText trackertrigger_Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Editsmstrigger);
    preferenceEditorUnique.putString("tracking_trigger",trackertrigger_Field.getText().toString());

    boolean Success = preferenceEditorUnique.commit();
    if(Success){
        //ALERT MESSAGE
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Successfully Saved Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Show code which is using for saving value in `SharedPreferences `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving data in preferences with key `tracking_trigger` but when retrieving data from the preferences, you are trying to get data corresponding to the key `tracker_trigger`which doesn't exists. That's why always returns the default value of `null`. Just make both the keys same.

Comment: I think I broke it trying to fix it, will test code and update answer asap

Comment: Thank You, yes it was a simple missight